# UIImagePickerController hide square selection in allowsEditing

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I would like to display a UIImagePickerController with the `allowsEditing` property set to `true`, since that gives you a nice view of the photo that you took with the ability to "Retake" or "Use Photo".
However, I don't want the user to be able to crop the image, so it makes sense to somehow hide that square overlay in that view.
I'm attaching a screenshot for clarification.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so . allowsEditing has any relation with retake and use photo option ? Did you test that properly ?

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerController is a simple-minded lazy way to supply an image-capturing interface. If you adopt it, you must simply accept that. Either you buy into UIImagePickerController for capturing an image or you don’t. If you do, you must accept its limitations.

You can turn off `allowsEditing` and roll your own interface by removing the default controls and supplying new ones, and you can even push your own secondary interface onto the picker controller (because it is a navigation controller); but you cannot turn on `allowsEditing` and then struggle against the interface that it gives you.

On the other hand, if you’re willing to do a little work — that is, if you *don’t* buy into UIImagePickerController — then you simply use AVFoundation to take the photo and build your own interface completely from scratch. Now you can have any interface you like.